# Открыть поле формы по нажатию чекбокса

Tags: html

Как открыть поле mail в форме по нажатию чекбокса? Если отжато, то оно должно быть скрыто.

```
<form method="POST" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" required>
    <input name='email' type='checkbox' value="1"> 
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="mail">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Присоединиться" class="btn btn-success">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Например, добавить в css:

```
input[name="mail"]{
  visibility: hidden; 
}
input[name="email"]:checked ~ input[name="mail"]{
  visibility: visible;
}
```